# Inserting values to SQL Server Database

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I'm working with python and microsoft sql server and want to get datavalues into my database vertically but the database approves the values ​​horizontally. I read the files using pd.Excelfile. An example is:

The database approves these vertical values:

```
A 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
B 3 4 5 6 7 8 2 6 7
C 8 9 4 6 3 2 5 1 3
```

but I would rather read it horizontally:

```
A B C
1 3 8
2 4 9
3 5 4
4 6 6
5 7 3
6 8 2
7 6 5
8 7 1
```

Hope my explanation was clearly described, appreciate the answers

Comment: Sounds like a `pivot` table of sorts is required

Comment: Just [transpose](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) the DataFrame?

Comment: What does approves mean here: *database approves these vertical values*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply`  :

```
with t1 as (
     select t.col, tt.cols, row_number() over (partition by t.col order by cols) seq
     from table t cross apply
         ( values (col1), (col2), . . . 
         ) tt (cols)
)
select max(case when col = 'A' then cols end) as [A],
       max(case when col = 'B' then cols end) as [B],
       max(case when col = 'C' then cols end) as [C]
from t1
group by seq;
```